# how can I create subheading in material UI table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using a material UI table what my task is in the second row in the Alert List I need to make three subheadings under Alert List not sure how can pass in material UI table I am aware like I can use `colSpan={3}` `rowSpan={3`} but I make a table for dynamic use of table so whatever I pass in `headshells` table data will change according to if any other way I need to use I can change I need to arange properly I am also adding code sandbox link.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { makeStyles, Table, TableBody, Paper } from "@material-ui/core";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TablePagination from "@material-ui/core/TablePagination";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import TableSortLabel from "@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel";

function createData(name, list, fat, carbs, protein) {
  return { name, list, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData("Cupcake", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData("Donut", 452, 25.0, 51, 4.9),
  createData("Eclair", 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData("Frozen yoghurt", 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Honeycomb", 408, 3.2, 87, 6.5),
  createData("Ice cream sandwich", 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData("Jelly Bean", 375, 0.0, 94, 0.0),
  createData("KitKat", 518, 26.0, 65, 7.0),
  createData("Lollipop", 392, 0.2, 98, 0.0),
  createData("Marshmallow", 318, 0, 81, 2.0),
  createData("Nougat", 360, 19.0, 9, 37.0),
  createData("Oreo", 437, 18.0, 63, 4.0)
];

function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy) {
  if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

function getComparator(order, orderBy) {
  return order === "desc"
    ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
    : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
}

function stableSort(array, comparator) {
  const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
  stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
    const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
    if (order !== 0) return order;
    return a[1] - b[1];
  });
  return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
}

const headCells = [
  {
    id: "name",
    numeric: false,
    disablePadding: true,
    label: "Dessert (100g serving)"
  },
  { id: "list", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Alert List" },
  { id: "fat", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Fat (g)" },
  { id: "carbs", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Carbs (g)" },
  { id: "protein", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Protein (g)" }
];

function EnhancedTableHead(props) {
  const {
    classes,
    onSelectAllClick,
    order,
    orderBy,
    numSelected,
    rowCount,
    onRequestSort
  } = props;
  const createSortHandler = (property) => (event) => {
    onRequestSort(event, property);
  };

  return (
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        {headCells.map((headCell) => (
          <TableCell
            key={headCell.id}
            padding={headCell.disablePadding ? "none" : "normal"}
            sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
          >
            <TableSortLabel
              active={orderBy === headCell.id}
              direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : "asc"}
              onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
            >
              {headCell.label}
              {orderBy === headCell.id ? (
                <span className={classes.visuallyHidden}>
                  {order === "desc" ? "sorted descending" : "sorted ascending"}
                </span>
              ) : null}
            </TableSortLabel>
          </TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
  );
}

EnhancedTableHead.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  numSelected: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  onRequestSort: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onSelectAllClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  order: PropTypes.oneOf(["asc", "desc"]).isRequired,
  orderBy: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  rowCount: PropTypes.number.isRequired
};

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%"
  },
  paper: {
    width: "100%",
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  table: {
    minWidth: 750
  },
  visuallyHidden: {
    border: 0,
    clip: "rect(0 0 0 0)",
    height: 1,
    margin: -1,
    overflow: "hidden",
    padding: 0,
    position: "absolute",
    top: 20,
    width: 1
  }
}));

export default function EnhancedTable() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [order, setOrder] = React.useState("asc");
  const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = React.useState("list");
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(5);

  const handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
    const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === "asc";
    setOrder(isAsc ? "desc" : "asc");
    setOrderBy(property);
  };

  const handleSelectAllClick = (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      const newSelecteds = rows.map((n) => n.name);
      setSelected(newSelecteds);
      return;
    }
    setSelected([]);
  };

  const handleClick = (event, name) => {
    const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(name);
    let newSelected = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, name);
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(
        selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1)
      );
    }

    setSelected(newSelected);
  };

  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
    setPage(0);
  };

  const isSelected = (name) => selected.indexOf(name) !== -1;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <TableContainer>
          <Table
            className={classes.table}
            aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
            size="medium"
            aria-label="enhanced table"
          >
            <EnhancedTableHead
              classes={classes}
              numSelected={selected.length}
              order={order}
              orderBy={orderBy}
              onSelectAllClick={handleSelectAllClick}
              onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
              rowCount={rows.length}
            />
            <TableBody>
              {stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map((row, index) => {
                  const isItemSelected = isSelected(row.name);

                  return (
                    <TableRow
                      hover
                      onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row.name)}
                      role="checkbox"
                      aria-checked={isItemSelected}
                      tabIndex={-1}
                      key={row.name}
                      selected={isItemSelected}
                    >
                      {headCells.map((column) => {
                        const value = row[column.id];
                        return (
                          <TableCell key={column.id} align={column.align}>
                            {column.format && typeof value === "number"
                              ? column.format(value)
                              : value}
                          </TableCell>
                        );
                      })}
                    </TableRow>
                  );
                })}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        <TablePagination
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
          component="div"
          count={rows.length}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          page={page}
          onPageChange={handleChangePage}
          onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-uj56u?file=/demo.js:0-7944)